# Compare Values in Different Sheets, then copy corresponding cell if matching (Excel 2013)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

For Excel 2013, please...

- FIRST off, I'm looking for a formula solution, not macro or such. Just maybe VLOOKUP, or INDEX... those sorts of simple solutions (Just copy paste on a cell).
- **HERE's the problem:** I got two Sheets: **Sheet1** contains presentation data, **Sheet2 (reference**) contains reference data.
- **Sheet2** has data that's not arranged. It's got data I copy-pasted from an ever-changing source.
- I want to always update **Sheet1's** data using **Sheet2**.

Here's what they look like (I'll just mockup superhero names and corresponding values):

I got old/existing data in Sheet1, hence:

```
Sheet1

Column A           Column B
Daredevil          /me want output here/
Spider-Man         /output/
Cyclops            /output/
Wolverine          /output/
Spider-Woman       /output/
Lockheed           /output/
Warpath            /output/
```

I got new data in Sheet2, hence:

```
Sheet2

A   Column B       Column C
     Lockheed      Violet
     The Streak    Red
     Cyclops       Blue
     Warpath       Black
     Wolverine     Yellow
     Daredevil     Red
     Kick-Puncher  Red
     Havok         Violet
```

- Now, if **Sheet1's Column A** match with **Sheet2's Column B**, I want **Sheet1's Column B** to display **Sheet2's Column C**, corresponding to the matching value (same row from any cell, but in this case, a cell in Column C);
- If there's no match, I want it to display: "whatevs".
  **Below is a sample output** I'm aiming for:

  ```
  Sheet1

  Column A          Column B
  Daredevil              Red
  Spider-Man           whatevs
  Cyclops                Blue
  Wolverine            Yellow
  Spider-Woman         whatevs
  Lockheed             Violet
  Warpath               Black
  ```

I've wasted two working days at this already :'( After that, I've decided I'll let the experts handle this. I can't!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems a very complicated way to describe a simple VLOOKUP type requirement (and you may have issues if you have NBSPs in your data) but basically I think what you are looking for is:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0),"whatevs")
```

in Sheet1 B2 copied down to suit.

Comment: Hahah, sorry @pnuts.. . I was aiming for a very visual explanation.. . and I've been confused about how to do it also. I knew it was simple for you guys, though. :') </br>Thank you. I'll try this when I got more time. (tomorrow or Sunday)

Comment: Hi @pnuts sorry for the delay in reply. Very busy the past 2 days.
I tested it, but I can't make it to work :'/
Please see linked file (in OneDrive) of test Excel:
[link]http://1drv.ms/1E5axOT
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on your shared file.. apparently, it is somewhat different from the question text :

> got two Sheets: **Sheet1** contains presentation data, **Sheet2** (reference) contains reference data.

So.. what I did is.. rename the sheet : Reference data sheet as 'ref', and Presentation as 'prsntn'

In prsntn!B2 cell put this.. and drag downward.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(ref!C:C,MATCH(prsentn!A2,ref!B:B,0)),"whatevs")
```

done.

Explanation : try crunching this [link](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) let me know where you stuck, I'll try my best to assist.

Hope it helps.